# Отправить GET запрос на HTTPS на питоне

Tags: python, http, сокет, get

Задача отправить сырой GET запрос на HTTP (конкретно на api.telegram.org)
Используя только библиотеку socket().
Подключиться на api.telegram.org по 443 порту и отправить GET запрос, а потом прочитать ответ.

Используется такой код клиента:

```
message = b'''GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.telegram.org
'''

sock = socket.socket()
sock.connect(('api.telegram.org', 443))
sock.send(message)
data = sock.recv(1024)
sock.close()
```

Любые попытки собрать пакет GET запроса оканчиваются ошибкой. Ругается, что неправильный запрос (400 ошибка). Иногда, что на HTTPS порт отправляется HTTP запрос.
Вариантов GET запроса перебрано уйма. Даже запрос от браузера не помогает. Документаций на этот счет найти не вышло.

Comment: не только шифрованные, а еще и сжатые https://docs.python.org/3/library/gzip.html

Comment: @Oopss в данном случае автоматически сжатие не применяется, но чтобы сервер точно не отдавал сжатый контент, можно добавить в заголовок HTTP запроса `Accept-Encoding: identity`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25046671/4752653

Answer (score 6):

Для запросов на 443 порт (https) нужно использовать TLS/SSL шифрование, а не отправлять голые HTTP запросы.

На основе примеров из документации (https://docs.python.org/3/library/ssl.html):

```
import socket
import ssl

hostname = 'api.telegram.org'
context = ssl.create_default_context()

# Переносы строк лучше явно прописать как \r\n
# В конце должно быть два переноса строки, иначе это не будет считаться полным запросом,
# и сервер будет бесконечно ждать продолжения
message = b'''GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: api.telegram.org

'''.replace(b"\n", b"\r\n")

with socket.create_connection((hostname, 443)) as sock:
    with context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=hostname) as ssock:
        ssock.send(message)
        data = ssock.recv(1024)
        print(data.decode())
```

Результат:

```http
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
Server: nginx/1.18.0
Date: Wed, 18 Oct 2023 08:57:00 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 145
Connection: keep-alive
Location: https://core.telegram.org/bots
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Length,Content-Type,Date,Server,Connection

<html>
<head><title>302 Found</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>302 Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Видим, что прилетел ответ [HTTP 302](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) (редирект), адрес редиректа - `https://core.telegram.org/bots`, это та же страница, которая откроется в браузере, если попытаться открыть https://api.telegram.org